# Ember - manually link to another model via store or new ajax call

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Ember newb here...

```
// working with
Ember      : 1.13.6
Ember Data : 1.13.7
```

__

```
/api/locations

{
  "locations":[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "uri":"/location/1",
      "name":"ATLANTA"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "uri":"/location/2",
      "name":"NORTH VIRGINIA"
   }
 ]
}
```

__

```
/api/hosts/1/show

{
  "id": 1,
  "active": true,
  "location_uri": "/location/1"
}
```

A single host includes a reference back to a location but I don't have a location id just the "location_uri" when viewing the host info, which is something I'm hoping I can use to manually look up this record and include in the model when displaying the host show page.

[image]
         .......I would like to display the location's name instead of this uri and I would like to link it back to the actual location form the host show page. I need some ideas of how to do this?

I think understand how to do find a record in my store like so:

`this.store.find('location', {uri: this.model('location')})`

but where and when to use is where I'm having trouble. Or even if I just manually made an api call to get the location data and somehow included it in my host show model would be a useful trick.

I'm pretty sure I can't use relationships for this because it doesn't really exist in the JSON right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wasn't able to get the JSON API relationship working or manufactured correctly but did come up with what I think is a simple solution to what I was trying to achieve.

`serializers/applicaiton.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({

 /** 
  * temporarily create location property
  * parse the id out of the location_uri "/location/1", need just "1"
  */
 normalize: function (type, hash, property) {
    if (!!hash.location_uri) {
      json['location'] = parseFloat(hash.location_uri.match(/\d+/g));
    }
 },

 /** 
  * when submitting C_UD request remove the manufactured location
  */
 serialize: function (snapshot) {
    delete json['location'];
 }

});
```

In my `host model` I assign the store belongsTo helper to the manufactured location.

`models/host.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  uri: attr(),
  active: attr('boolean'),
  location_uri: attr(),
  location: DS.belongsTo('location', {async: true})
});
```

In my templates I can now do this:

```
{{#link-to 'location.show' host.location.id }}{{host.location.name}}{{/link-to}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do this with relationships but you have to override you adapter and/or serializer.

If you extend the JSONAPISerializer you would probably serialize your host response into something like this:

```
{
  id: "1",
  type: "host",
  attributes: {
    active: true
  },
  relationships: {
    location: {
      links: {
        related: "/location/1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming this is your `/models/host.js`:
    export DS.Model.extend({
      active: DS.attr('boolean'),
      location: DS.belongsTo('location')
    });

And this is your `models/location.js`:
    export DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string')
    })

Then you can do something like

```
this.store.find('host', '1').then(host => console.log(Ember.get(host, 'location.name')))
```

---

I would recommend to never override `uri` in your `.find()` call, but set this on your adapter, and build a nice serializer.

Comment: FYI I'm going to give this a try soon.

Comment: Do I have to use JSONAPISerializer in order to get the relationship. I'm currently using just JSONSerializer.

Comment: You can use the `JSONSerializer`. It just expects another structure. Ember data internally uses the JSONAPI structure, so I think if you have to do manual conversion you should use the `JSONAPISerializer`. The `JSONSerializer` expects a `links` object with the relationship links.